# How can I create an "inner ring" for labels when using polar coordinates in ggplot a with log scale

Tags: r, ggplot2

I can use ggplot and coord_polar()and ylim(-2000, 500) to create a plot like this:
[polar plot with inner ring to show the "x-axis" group labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB1t0.png)
which has an empty inner ring which displays the group labels on the "former" x-axis.

But when I have a wider range of numbers and use  scale_y_continuous(trans='log10'), I get this:
[polar plot with log scale... no inner ring](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HRcXn.png)
in which all the bars start at the very center (origin) with now way to insert the group labels in a blank inner ring. I've tried numerous numerous things to get an empty inner ring (in which to display group labels), but it appears log scaled polar ggplots don't permit this, at least not trivially. Any way to accomplish this?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick in this case is not to set the limits to a negative value, but raise a positive number to a negative power. You may recall that `log(0)` evaluates to `-Inf` and `log(-1)` evaluates to `NaN`. Example with a standard dataset below.

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mpg, aes(interaction(year, cyl))) +
  geom_bar() +
  annotate(
    "segment",
    x = c(0.55, 2.55, 3.55, 5.55),
    xend = c(2.45, 3.45, 5.45, 7.45),
    y = 1e0, yend = 1e0, size = 2
  ) +
  annotate(
    "text",
    x = c(1.5, 3, 4.5, 6.5),
    y = 5e-1, label = c("4", "5", "6", "8")
  ) +
  scale_y_log10(limits = c(1e-1, NA)) +
  coord_polar()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks. This worked like a charm.